# Cannot Connect from PHP script to AWS database

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo, tcp

I'm trying to connect to an aws rds that I created. I can connect no problem using MySQL Workbench but not from the PHP script which I have uploaded to a server. I have a feeling it is something to do with the permissions but I am not sure. Could someone point me in the right direction. Below is the PHP code I am using

```
<?php
//Database configuration

$dbhost = $_SERVER['https://address.to.aws.rds/rds/home?region=us-west-2'];
$dbport = $_SERVER['3306'];
$dbname = $_SERVER['test_db_name'];

$dsn = "mysql:host={$dbhost};port={$dbport};dbname={$dbname}";
$username = $_SERVER['username'];
$password = $_SERVER['password'];

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
}
```

The error I get when I upload and run this script is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' in /home2/betamath/public_html/graspe/db.php:12 Stack trace: #0 /home2/betamath/public_html/graspe/db.php(12): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=;por...', NULL, NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /home2/betamath/public_html/graspe/db.php on line 12
```

Line 12 is `$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);`

The permissions I have set up for the aws rds are

```
HTTP            TCP      80      0.0.0.0/0

SSH             TCP      22      0.0.0.0/0

MySQL/AURORA    TCP      3306    0.0.0.0/0

HTTPS           TCP      443     0.0.0.0/0
```

Again, any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure when you created the RDS the User name used was root? RDS never gives a root access.

Comment: Where is the PHP server located?

Comment: the username is not root but that is what it is showing me. The server is located in Texas in the USA.

Comment: I mean if it is in shared hosting it may be locked down for getting back out in some hosting environments. Not where on a map

Comment: :-) Sorry, It is a shared server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$dbname = "database_name";
$dbuser = "database_user"; 
$dbpass = "database_password"; 
$dbhost01 = "user.regioninfo.rds.amazonaws.com"; // did not use http or https; info provided from AWS
$dbport = 3306;

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost01;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. I now get the error message

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/rds/home?region=us-west-2' (0)' in /home2/betamath/public_html/graspe/db.php:10 Stack trace: #0 /home2/betamath/public_html/graspe/db.php(10): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=us-w...', 'uname', 'pword') #1 {main} thrown in /home2/betamath/public_html/graspe/db.php on line 10

I've tried adding the https:// to the start of the URL but I get the same error

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct address for an RDS server. At least that's not what my address looks like.

Comment: When looking at the RDS dashboard, get the instance's endpoint. I use everything except the colon and the port number (`:3306`).

Comment: You were right. I had the wrong endpoint. Couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks so much.